# SharePoint 2013 - Is there a way to get columns headers to wordwrap and freeze

Tags: 2013

I've created a custom list in SharePoint 2013 that has 28 columns.  I'd like to remove the white spaces between the columns and wordwrap the headers.  I'd also like to have the headers freeze at the top when scrolling down the list.

I've search the site and tried numerous suggestions without luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Was one of the suggestion is to create views instead of having 28 columns in one list?! You might be over engineering this list, and it would be easier to create multiple lists and link them using lookup columns. I am sure there are ways to remove the spaces (not sure about freezing the header) using css, but in my opinion, the issue could be bigger than that!

Update: I found a solution here for the sticky header:

http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/